# How to use line breaks in Flex with PHP string

Tags: php, mysql, apache-flex

This is the MXML I have

```
<mx:Text id="name" styleName="textStyle" maxWidth="400"></mx:Text>
```

Then in the same file I have :

```
<mx:Script>
    <![CDATA[

    private function init():void
    {
       name.text = data.string;
    }

    ]]>
</mx:Script>
```

`data.string` comes from the DB and it contains this :

```
"This is a string \n with two lines."
```

I also tried this :

```
"This is a string &#13; with two lines."
```

None of them create a new line in flex they are both rendered to the screen as `\n` and `&#13;`.

How can I create a new line with a string that is coming from the database?

If I type `\n` like this in the code it works :

```
name.text = "test \n test";
```

but if I do `name.text=data.string;` it doesn't even though `data.string` has the exact same value.

Comment: Is the data you are fetching from the database the same every time or is it user input data that is contently changing?

Comment: It is always the same This is string &#13; with two lines. or  This is string \n with two lines.

Comment: Let me get this straight, you are trying to echo or place the echo'd text on two different lines? Or are they meant to filter into two different table fields displayed on the page?

Comment: No its just one line of text which contains \n or &#13;. I get this text from the database and try to display it in Flex but it doesnt create a new line instead it display \n or &#13;

Comment: I don't know about flex but does it compile with any html elements? Could you potentially add a <br /> to the string? You say you are using some php so tat should work if you are echo'ing the text via php, but I'm not sure how it will behave withing flex. [According to Adobe you can use html in flex, but it will require some extra code](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=textcontrols_04.html). Sorry that is all I can offer, I wish I knew more about Flex and what it does and does not recognize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I run this on the string coming from the DB it works:

```
string.split("\\n").join("\n");
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that you can find something you want in this site.

http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/flex-php-tutorial-transmitting-data-using-json

Comment: Couldn't find anything about new lines on this site.

Answer (score 1):

Or you can use String.replace:

```
string.replace(/\\n/g,'\n')
```