# My AS3 isn't reading line breaks (/n or \n) from imported XML

Tags: xml, actionscript-3

I started creating a banner that contains several images/links using strings from an array variable but as we progress, I wanted to add XML to the mix so that we can update it more efficiently.

This text appears in a tool tip as the user mouses over an image on the banner. It worked just fine in the array variable, but when pulled from XML it shows the \n, \n, /n, \r\n, and everything else I could find to try. A `</br>` gives me an error. I've tried .toString(), found the ignoreProcessingInstructions property and tried turning it off. Just nothing. Is there something really simple that I am just not seeing?

So here's what works: 
from my AS3 Array variable: `"Working with Alerts\nand Notifications" //this works fine`

from my XML: `Working with Alerts\nand Notifications //this returns everything inside of the tags, including the \n.`

The line for feeding the text into the `tip: tip.tipTitleField.text = titleText[refNum].toString(); //has been tried without .toString() and with .toString() inside of the [], but it always returns the same... correct string, just with the \n plainly visible.`

Thank you for any advice, Chris

Comment: For future reference, if you are saving HTML in XML, make sure you wrap  each string in `<![CDATA[ HTML Here ]]>` and then use the `htmlText` property of your `TextField`

Comment: Thank you, I am somewhat novice, but will hopefully learn this quickly! I saw and tried the .htmlText property before, but without the brackets in my XML that would explain the error messages!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try :

```
titleText[refNum].replace(/\\n/g,'\n');
```

or

```
titleText[refNum].split("\\n").join("\n");
```

I had the same [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6448510/how-to-use-line-breaks-in-flex-with-php-string) with strings coming from php not displaying new lines in Flex, maybe it helps.

Comment: Alright, Barış Uşaklı, you are my favorite person today. This worked perfectly. Thank you very much!

Comment: Have you got a solution for replacing all the `\\n`s with `\n`s after loading the XML? So that when you need to load strings from the XML it's all clean and tidy?